# iTunes sync does not delete songs

Tags: iphone, itunes

My wife's iPhone 4 has some albums synced on her iPhone that are not selected to be synced in iTunes.

She has "Selected playlists, artists, albums and genres" selected.

She is using a wired sync and Wireless Sync is disabled.

/edit
All her content in iTunes, and that synced to the iPhone, is ripped from the original CD.
/endedit

- No playlist contains this album
- the artist is not selected
- the album is not selected
- no genres are ticked at all

How is the album still there after sync?

Please note, I told her about the ability to remove the album from within Music on the iPhone, this question is purely about why the album is still there after a sync with iTunes.

/edit
All her content in iTunes, and that synced to the iPhone, is ripped from the original CD.  She is not using iTunes Match.
/endedit

Comment: Does she sync her "Recently played" playlist?

Comment: nice idea, but no; and over time if that were the case I'd have thought that it would get removed by a future sync

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Sync only checked songs and videos" was un-ticked.

When an iOS device is connected to iTunes, under the device's Summary tab, the Options section has a checkbox Named "Sync only checked songs and videos"; this option enforces the removal of music that is not set to sync if it has been synced to the device in the past.

Ticking the box and then syncing removed the offending album.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can use [DiskAid](http://www.digidna.net/products/diskaid#dataIntLnk) to safely access the iOS file system and delete Music/Data. The app costs $24.99, but you can get it for free on an educational license (have a .edu email ID).</strike>

Failing that, a restore might be the best option.

My bad, I didn't read the question properly.

This [Apple forum post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3565960?start=0&tstart=0) seems to suggest that songs downloaded by iTunes Match are not 'synced' in with iTunes, but via the iCloud. Maybe, these albums are from iTunes Match?

That post also details a way to delete all music from your iPhone (as opposed to deleting individual songs or albums):

> You can do this on your iPhone by going to Settings > General > Usage. Wait a few seconds for the usage statistics to appear, then choose Music. Tap Edit and then the delete symbol next to “All Music”.
>
> This will delete all the music from the phone. After this songs will still be visible (with clouds next to them). You can still play them from iTunes Match and they will be downloaded again; this will not remove them from iTunes Match.

: [source](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16989768#16989768)

Does this answer your question?

Comment: you can remove music from the iPhone within iOS as I noted in the question.  The question is about how it got there and why it won't delete using iTunes.

Comment: She is not using iTunes Match, all the content in iTunes are albums ripped from the original CD's